# Setting Up Symfony 2 - Cannot Load app.php Resource

Tags: symfony

I'm having trouble with setting up my Symfony2 production environment.  The dev environment through *app_dev.php* works fine, but production through *app.php* leades to a 500 Internal Server Error, and this message in the Symfony error log:

```
[2011-08-28 10:09:11] request.CRITICAL: Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot load resource ".". (uncaught exception) at /var/www/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/Loader.php line 75 [] []
```

Don't know how to solve this, or even stack trace it...

Comment: Can we see your production config.yml files for routing and general config?

Answer (score 8):

Happened to me when I updated the `Liip/ImagineBundle`.

In older versions of this bundle it required this in your routing:

```
_imagine:
    resource: .
    type:     imagine
```

In the new versions this is to be replaced by:

```
_liip_imagine:
    resource: "@LiipImagineBundle/Resources/config/routing.yaml"
```

So in my case the problem was I updated the bundle via composer, but did not update the `routing.yml`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem. Try to add:

assetic:
    use_controller: true

in /app/config/config_prod.yml  and clean cache after that (rm -fr /app/cache/*)

Comment: Can you explain how does this help? and what could've changed that caused this problem and has to be solved by adding that config?

Comment: this is wrong, you don't want to use the assetic controllers in production, instead you need to dump your assets using `app/console assetic:dump --env prod`

Answer (score 4):

if you have these problems in production environment and you use assetic, then check if you don't have this:

```
_assetic:
    resource: .
    type:     assetic
```

in your config file (normally this is in config_dev.yml only, not in production)... in other case try to check other routes with `resource: .`

Comment: This is in routing_dev.yml not config_dev.yml

Answer (score 1):

I had faced a similar issue while hosting symfony2 project to a godaddy windows shared hosting with php5.3 support and fixed it by providing write permission to the symfony2 directories and creating an iis virtual directory for the symfony project directory.

Answer (score 0):

For me this was caused because I wasn't sure where a blob of config was added to my `config.yml` and removed it because I didn't know what it did :)

So I downloaded a fresh copy of symfony2 and realized that the blob of code comes by default on a fresh install, so I put it back in and it all works. Here's what I had removed and I fixed the problem by putting it back in:

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    #java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        #closure:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/compiler.jar
        #yui_css:
        #    jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

then answer is in the routing.yml

there is a resource in there that was probably disabled and the reference is left.